# Developing Silverlight 1.0 Applications on VS2008 SP1

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2008-sp1

Can anyone point me to any guides, howto's or general documentation on how to develop Silverlight 1.0 (it has to be 1.0) on VS2008 SP1.

I have searched high and low for information, and it all seems to be out of date (referencing Silverlight 1.0 Tools for Visual Studio 2008 beta, release candidate and alpha packages) or just plain doesn't work under VS2008 SP1.

What do I need to install, and which project do I need to create?  I have installed the Silverlight 1.0 SDK, which gave me no starting point, the Silverlight 2.0 Tools for Visual Studio after a website suggested you could use that to develop 1.0 apps, but the suggested template doesn't exist, and Silverlight 3.0 Tools for Visual Studio, which was a last ditch resort.

Regards

Moo

Comment: A client has placed that restriction on us.  As they always do.

Comment: Your client has issues. There are no advantages to their request whatsoever. 1.0 wasn't really worth using in '07 and in this day and age it makes even less sense. My condolences, and good luck.

Comment: Agreed.  I can't think of a single reason for going with V1.  If I was starting an app right now, I can't think of a good reason not to target V4.  If they're concerned about penetration, point them to http://riastats.com/#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to install Expression Blend 2, as that still supports Silverlight 1.0.  Expression Blend 3 only supports later versions, and its a complete pain in the ass trying to find all the components for VS2005 or VS2008 to handle SL1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use VS 2005 for SL 1.0, as it was out in Mid-2007.